# Bypass conditional formatting limitations?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I have to color Calc rows, based on some string condition. So each time some string value appear in B column, the entire column is colored in certain color. It looks like on this image.

[image]

I need more strings and more conditions. How can I overcome this limitation?

Comment: This is a repeat of your last question.  I do not use openoffice-calc or libreoffice so can comment on an appropriate solution for them.  My solution to your last question works for Excel and has no limit on the number of different strings.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thanks. But OpenOffice and LibreOffice have limitations and I am not sure how to bypass them

Comment: I have no knowledge of LibreOffice.  I have used OpenOffice-Calc and know that it has a macro language based on VBA.  There is nothing complex in my Excel macro so perhaps it can be adapted for OpenOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Libreoffice 3.5 which no longer has this limitation.

For older Libreoffice version there should be an extension providing the same functionailty. Check in the Libreoffice extension repository if you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer states, LibreOffice 3.5 allows as many conditional formatting rules as you need. You just click the "add" button on the right hand side. To clear up an error in a previous post, VBA is minimally supported in Star/Open/Libre office. They have their own functions and BASIC programming rules that are similar, but most detailed VBA programs from excel spreadsheets need to be rewritten as the syntax is fairly different.

I don't know how long this link will be good for, but this is what I have been using as a guide for programming:
http://198.62.75.4/opt/sun_docs/C/solaris_10/SUNWsodoc/SO7BPG/